# Laravel - Changing the Base URL of the Reset Email URL that's being sent to users

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am using Laravel's default email functionality when sending the password reset link to users, and because of this, i wanted to change some parts of the email content that's being sent. One of those is the base URL of the reset link in the email.

In the email, it has this:

[image]

I wanted to change the Base URL `http://localhost:8081` into something different since I am hosting other web apps on a different domain.

How can I do that?

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You mean you have 2 servers. One for user to click reset password (an email will be sent to user). The other for handling reset password logic (after user click the link in email, fill new information and submit)

Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Reset Email Customization](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passwords#reset-email-customization) and domain you can set in `.env` for getting